# dimentions of images as an input of LeNet_5

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am still a beginner in deep learning, I am wondering is it necessary to have for the input images of a size equal to 32*32 (or X*X)? the dimensions of my images are 457*143.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement a LeNet and train it from the scratch, you don't have to resize your images. However, if you want to do **transfer learning**, you'd better resize your images according to the image size of the dataset on which your neural net is already trained.